# Why setNeedsDisplay required when initWithNibName used

Tags: ios

I have custom UIViewController class called MSPageViewController with and associated nib file.  I have an IBOutlet which is a UIImageView called pageImage.

Now, I want to use this view controller in another UIViewController which will display a series of my custom MSPageViewController in a UIPageViewController. So, I use the following code:

// alloc and init my custom view controller

```
MSPageViewController *page1 = [[MSPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MSPageViewController" bundle:nil];
```

// I must call this or, the image that I set below will always be null
// why?  I guess it's because the view hasn't been drawn yet because it hasn't been displayed, so I need to force the redraw - but this is my question.  Is this is the right approach?

```
[page1.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

// set the image

```
page1.pageImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorialPage1.png"];
```

// make my array of view controllers, it expects an array because could be double-sided

```
NSArray *viewController = [NSArray page1];
```

// pass the array that contains my custom view controller

```
[self.pageController setViewControllers:viewController direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

So am I doing this right?  I have to force the redraw so that my outlets exist when I try to assign to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, pageImage (a UIImageView?) is likely not loaded from the nib yet when you're accessing it.

If you have a custom getter for pageImage, you could do the following:

```
- (UIImageView*) pageImage
{
    [self view];
    return _pageImage; // assuming the property backing ivar is synthesized as _pageImage.
}
```

But my personal preference would be to not expose the imageview itself and just expose a property for image.  Then you can set the image to the viewcontroller regardless of it's loaded state, and internally set it to the imageView once the view loads:

```
- (void) setImage: (UIImage*) image
{
    _image = image;

    if ( self.isViewLoaded )
    {
         self.pageImage.image = image;
    }
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.pageImage.image = self.image;
}
```

Comment: +1, elegant solution. I guess there's a slight mistake, though: make that last line `self.pageImage.image = self.image;`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the `setNeedsDisplay` part that you "need", it's the `self.view` part. By accessing the `view` property you are forcing the view controller to actually load the NIB. I guess that as a side effect of this, the `pageImage` property is populated as well (and was `nil` before you called `self.view`).

So, just calling `self.view;` instead of `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` should be enough.

Comment: Ok, this is very helpful.  But, if I use the getter to get the view and I don't actually need the view (so, I don't assign it anywhere) xcode complains that property access result is unused.  What's the recommend approach here?

Comment: You could either try the "old" form `[self view];` or you can call a harmless method on `self.view`... like `setNeedsDisplay` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you moved some code to the viewDidLoad method you would be guaranteed that the view had been drawn.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called when the view is in memory (instantiated, not yet "drawn").

Comment: I can't move it to the viewDidLoad method because I don't know what the image will be until the other viewcontroller decides what it will be.